# "Merge" SQL results in C# with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, merge, resultset

everyone. I'm having trouble finding the best way to retrieve data from a N-N relationship...

I have the following SQL query and resultset:

```
select
    p.PersonID,
    Name,
    PhoneNumber
from Persons p
left join PhoneNumbers n on p.PersonID = n.PersonID;

PersonID    Name         PhoneNumber
----------- ------------ --------------------
1           John         1111111
1           John         2222222
1           John         3333333
2           Maria        4444444
2           Maria        5555555
3           Billy        6666666
```

What I want to do in my client application (C#) is to parse those results into a set of objects. Right now I have the following code, but I wonder if there is a better way to do it...

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public List<PhoneNumbers> PhoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumbers>();
}

public class PhoneNumbers
{
    public Person Owner;
    public string PhoneNumber;
}

public List<Person> GetPersons()
{
    const string query = @"select
                             p.PersonID,
                             Name,
                             PhoneNumber
                           from Persons p
                           left join PhoneNumbers n on p.PersonID = n.PersonID;";

    DataTable dataTable = Select(query);

    var groups = from row in dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                 group row by row["PersonID"];

    List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        Person person = new Person
        {
            ID = (int)group.ElementAt(0)["PersonID"],
            Name = group.ElementAt(0)["Name"] as string
        };

        foreach (var row in group)
        {
            person.PhoneNumbers.Add(new PhoneNumbers
            {
                Owner = person,
                PhoneNumber = row["PhoneNumber"] as string
            });
        }

        persons.Add(person);
    }

    return persons;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use LINQ-SQL. Can you show the database table schema?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an **ORM** tool?

ORM, Object-relational mapping, is tool that allows you to query and manipulate data from a database using an object paradigm. *Generally speaking*, this means you will have C# objects representing your tables.

It also means you can use *LINQ* to query your database, instead of *SQL*. The *ORM*, will translate the *LINQ* to *SQL*, and pass on the execution to the database. On the return trip, it will map the results to C# object, which are much easier for you to work with.

There are quite a few to choose from, but some of the popular ones on .NET stack include:

- [Entity Framwework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/ef.aspx) (Microsoft's own implementation)
- [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/)
- [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)

Comment: Yup, I have. I want to try it later on in other projects, but this time I really have to do it with ADO.NET. Thanks a lot though

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing. It's far from the best, but at least it's better than before.

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public List<PhoneNumbers> PhoneNumbers;
}

public class PhoneNumbers
{
    public int PersonID;
    public string PhoneNumber;
}

public List<Person> GetPersons()
{
    const string query = @"select
                             p.PersonID,
                             Name,
                             PhoneNumber
                           from Persons p
                           left join PhoneNumbers n on p.PersonID = n.PersonID;";

    DataTable dataTable = Select(query);

    return (from row in dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        group row by row["PersonID"] into rows
        select new Person
        {
            ID = (int) rows.Key,
            Name = rows.First()["Name"] as string,
            PhoneNumbers = (from r in rows
                select new PhoneNumbers
                {
                    PersonID = (int) rows.Key,
                    PhoneNumber = rows.First()["PhoneNumber"] as string
                }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
}
```